# How to make jQuery Scrolling Top to bottom and Bottom to Top Slow Animation on Landing page menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I am creating a Landing page website.
Nav link is working when click on it it's goes to bottom and then bottom to top.
But i want to make it slow with jQuery Animation.
Please check my code and tell me where i am wrong.
Thank you.

```
// Smooth Scrolling nav links
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(event) {
var target = $( $(this).attr('href') );
if( target.length ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: target.offset().top,
        scrollBottom: target.offset().bottom
    }, 1000);
} });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is fine and works, you simply forgot to put a comma after `target.offset().top`

Have a look here for a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/L02tck8x/

Comment: sir i put a comma after target.offset().top, but its only animate top to bottom, it's not working bottom to top.

Comment: It works completely fine for me. I have updated my answer with a fiddle.

Comment: Yes it's Conflict jQuery code.
But now it's working.
Thank you fshock

Comment: Glad that helped :)

Answer (score 2):

You can also try like below

HTML:

```
 Link: <a href="#toBottom" class="toBottom">Scroll to Bottom &darr;</a>
 Target: <a name="toBottom"></a>

 Link: <a href="#toTop" class="toTop">Scroll to TOP &uarr;</a>
 Target: <a name="toTop"></a>
```

JS

```
$('.toTop ').click(function(){
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 600);
  return false;
});
$('.toBottom').click(function(){
  $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $(document).height()}, 600);
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Thank you Kuncham Vasu Sir.